Using <number | null> or <number | undefined> in computed() or signals() doesn't work correctly when the value is 0
I'm trying to use singals and computed in my new Angular project, but I'm running into a problem.
I have a computed value, which contains an id, which is a number. This id will be set by user interaction. Before that it is not set, so I tried setting it to null (or undefined).
public someSignal = signal<number | null>(null);
public selectedId = computed(() => {
  var result: number | null = null;
  let value = someSignal();
  // do some computations
  return result;
});

Now I wanted to use this in the template.
<div *ngIf="selectedId() as id">Current id: {{ id }}</div>

But this only works if the id is not 0. As soon as it is zero it behaves as if it is null. I switched everything to number | undefined, but it resulted in the same problem. As far as I know there is only the special case of null >= 0 being true. But maybe something changed or signals and computed values work differently.
I know I can change it to -1 representing the "null" value, but I would like to know if there is some better solutions to use number | null or if that's just something we have to life with.
Thank you very much.

I suppose the *ngIf evaluates to false when the computed signal is 0. What about `*ngIf="(selectedId() as id) !== null" ?

You need to change the syntax, try sending the function as an arrow function inside the computed as shown below! also make sure you define a signal inside the computed, the computed will auto detect the changes and update the value along with the complex calculations!
import { NgIf } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, computed, signal } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [FormsModule, NgIf],
  template: `
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="input"/>
    <div *ngIf="selectedId() as id">Current id: {{id}}</div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  public input = signal<number | null>(null);

  public selectedId = computed(() => {
    var result: number | null = this.input();
    // do some computations
    return `result-${result}`;
  });
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

I'm sorry, I've updated my question. I'm doing all of those things. The problem arrises when the computed value also returns number | null.

@LetzFlow what is the problem you are facing in the stackblitz shared, plz modify the stackblitz with the issue replicated and share on the question and update me please

@LetzFlow 0 and null are both evaluated by javascript as false! so in if conditions write
if(value || value === 0)  this will allow zero also!
